# Can the verb 'abhorrent' be used in this way?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Sth is abhorrent to you means that you have hatred of it or you dislike it very much. For example, 'Racial discrimiantion is absolutely abhorrent to me'.  But Can I say sb is abhorrent to me?  For instance, The guy is abhorrent to me. Is the sentence accepatble?

Comment: *Abhorrent* is an adjective. The verb is *abhor*. You will find numerous examples online of the expression that *something is abhorrent to me* although my preference would be to say *I find something abhorrent*.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at how

> abhorrent

is usually used with [nouns to which abhorrent are often applied: behavior, act, crime, practice, thing.](http://wikidiff.com/repulsive/abhorrent) not so much directly with people.  If you find someone's *behavior abhorrent*, you will probably find them

> repulsive - *tending to rouse aversion*

which is how somebody would usually be described

> I am *repulsed* by that person's **abhorrent** behavior.
>   That person's **abhorrent** behavior *repulses* me.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is perfectly valid. If something is **abhorrent to** you it means you consider it totally unacceptable, or hate it very much.

- *Racism of any kind is **abhorrent to** me.* ([***Cambridge Dictionary***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abhorrent))

<sup>...**abhorrent** is an *adjective*</sup>